# counter value is increasing from other element

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the function below. It's taking the data from JSON and it's creating a menu item. The problem is when there are more than 2 menu items, and I try to increase the quantity of the first item then the value of the second item is increasing.

```
function ShowTheMenu(theCategoryId) {
        var parentEl = document.getElementById("itemlist");
        ClearMenu();
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].KategorijaBroj == theCategoryId) {
                // MAIN PARENT
                var itemBox = document.createElement("div");
                itemBox.classList.add("itembox");

                var itemImage = document.createElement("img");
                itemImage.classList.add("itemimage");
                itemImage.src = "/menuitemsimages/" + data[i].Image;

                var itemContent = document.createElement("div");
                itemContent.classList.add("itemcontent");

                var itemTitle = document.createElement("h3");
                itemTitle.classList.add("itemtitle");
                itemTitle.innerHTML = data[i].Title;

                var itemPrice = document.createElement("p");
                itemPrice.classList.add("itemprice");
                itemPrice.innerHTML = "$" + data[i].Price;


                var itemQnt = document.createElement("p");
                itemQnt.classList.add("quantity");
                itemQnt.innerHTML = "Quantity";

                var buttonsBox = document.createElement("div");
                buttonsBox.classList.add("divcontrolbtns");

                var itemQuantity = 0;
                var quantityValue = document.createElement("div");
                quantityValue.innerHTML = itemQuantity;

                var increaseBtn = document.createElement("div");
                increaseBtn.classList.add("controlbtns");
                increaseBtn.innerHTML = "+";
                increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if(itemQuantity < 10) {
                        itemQuantity++;
                    }
                    quantityValue.innerHTML = itemQuantity;
                })

                var decreaseBtn = document.createElement("div");
                decreaseBtn.classList.add("controlbtns");
                decreaseBtn.innerHTML = "-";
                decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if(itemQuantity > 0) {
                        itemQuantity--;
                    }
                    quantityValue.innerHTML = itemQuantity;
                })

                
                var itemAddToCart = document.createElement("button");
                itemAddToCart.classList.add("btn-add-to-cart");
                itemAddToCart.textContent = "Add to cart";

                var itemDesc = document.createElement("p");
                itemDesc.classList.add("itemdesc");
                itemDesc.innerHTML = data[i].Description;

               
                itemBox.appendChild(itemImage);

                itemContent.appendChild(itemTitle);
                itemContent.appendChild(itemDesc);
                itemContent.appendChild(itemPrice);
                itemContent.appendChild(itemAddToCart);
                itemContent.appendChild(itemQnt);

                buttonsBox.appendChild(increaseBtn);
                buttonsBox.appendChild(quantityValue);
                buttonsBox.appendChild(decreaseBtn);


                itemContent.appendChild(buttonsBox);

                itemBox.appendChild(itemContent);

                parentEl.appendChild(itemBox);
            }
        }

    }
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpFBu.png)

What should I do in order for the chosen menu item value to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do something like this bellow. I try to use same HTML structure that you use but to be honest, I suggest that you change a little bit ;)

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <script>
            // Qt
            var quantity = new Array();

            function ShowTheMenu(theCategoryId) {
              // Clear menu
              // ClearMenu();

              // bt+
              increaseBtn = (i) => {
                // Item target
                let item = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
                // Qt target
                let qtSpan = item.getElementsByClassName('qt');
                // Qt
                let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
                // Fix some errors
                if (qt === undefined || !qt) qt = 0;
                // Increase
                if (qt < 10) qt++;
                // Update
                qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt;
              };
              // bt-
              decreaseBtn = (i) => {
                // Item target
                let item = document.getElementById('item_' + i);
                // Qt target
                let qtSpan = item.getElementsByClassName('qt');
                // Qt
                let qt = parseInt(qtSpan[0].innerHTML);
                // Fix some errors
                if (qt === undefined || !qt) qt = 0;
                // Decrease
                if (qt > 0) qt--;
                // Update
                qtSpan[0].innerHTML = qt;
              };

              //
              var data = new Array();
              data[0] = {
                Image:
                  'https://s2.glbimg.com/WcYUQNaattnUf7d8U8MUBfk7loU=/620x430/e.glbimg.com/og/ed/f/original/2015/10/30/pizza.jpg',
                KategorijaBroj: 1,
                Title: 'Delicious Pizza',
                Price: 10,
                Description: 'Description test',
              };

              for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].KategorijaBroj == theCategoryId) {
                  // Img
                  let img = data[i].Image; // '/menuitemsimages/' + data[i].Image;
                  // Title
                  let title = data[i].Title;
                  // Price
                  let price = '$' + data[i].Price;
                  // Description
                  let desc = data[i].Description;
                  // Qtd
                  let qt = 2;

                  // Matriz
                  let newItem = `<div id="item_${i}" class="itembox">
                                      <div class="itemcontent">
                                        <img src="${img}" border=0 width=100/>
                                        <h3 class="itemtitle">${title}</h3>
                                        <p class="itemprice">${price}</p>
                                        <div class="quantity">
                                            <span>Quantity : </span>
                                            <span class="qt">${qt}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="controlbtns">
                                          <button class="addbtn" onClick="increaseBtn(${i})">+</button>
                                          <button class="removebtn" onClick="decreaseBtn(${i})">-</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="btn-add-to-cart">Add to cart</button>
                                        <p class="description">${desc}</p>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>`;

                  // Get the menulist itens
                  let parentEl = document.getElementById('itemlist');
                  // Add item
                  parentEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newItem);
                }
              }
            }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="itemlist"></div>
          <script>
            ShowTheMenu(1);
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: seems better, but I got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object.

Comment: Sorry dude, I changed the code. Try using ".innerHTML"

Comment: + and - are undefined, the quantity is not changing. Sorry

Comment: Sorry. I changed the code. Try again please ;)

Comment: I believe I have to do it the way I start it. I found an article where says, with a tick the functions won't have an effect at all, which in this case is true. The quantity is not changing. I appreciated your help :)

Comment: The problem is another. You have to change your counter. I´ll do some changes here and we try again. Please wait a second.

Comment: Sorry to do many changes dude but I needed to see the big screen. NOW I guess everything is ok :) . But test, and if no, let me know !

Comment: It's working smoothly now, thank you very much!!! Cheers!!!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you :)

Comment: I would suggest to just use `var data = []` in javascript and also adding a `const/let/var` before the functions expressions  (increaseBtn and decreaseBtn)

Comment: Yes @Y.Gherbi should be. But I tried to suggest something simples and next to the original code in a question. I think this is a way easier to peter understand. But your suggestion is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

It's because both items are sharing the same variable, in this case, `itemQuantity`.

**Option 1**

If they all should have their own counter I would recommend using an object for tracking this.

```js
const itemQuantity = {
  'item1': 2,
  'item2': 5
}
```

if you add some unique `class` or `id` to the element you can use this in your `onclick` event to use as a key. (Where I used 'item1' and 'item2')

**Option 2**

If you create a function that does everything that's inside your for loop and then just call that function it should also work. This works because every function then creates its own scoped variable of `itemQuanity`.

Go with whatever options feel best for now. How to manage data in your frontend has a lot of different ways and opinions. You'll quickly discover what works best in what scenario.

---

What Olavo Mello is mentioning in his answer could still make your code better. using string literals for small HTML snippets is often more readable than using `document.createElement()`. I would recommend fixing your counter issue first and then look if you could improve your code with Olavo Mello's answer in mind. Good luck :)